# Best practice for declaring an empty variable

Tags: python, string, declare

I know Python is a dynamic language and declaring variables before-hand is generally not necessary, but in the case where I need to create a variable and then give it a value later, both of the following methods work:

```
some_variable = '' 
some_variable = str()
```

Is there a difference between both of these and which is considered best practice?

**Example:**

```
some_variable = str() 

for number in range(10): 
    some_variable += str(number)
print(some_variable)
```

Works for both `some_variable = ''` and `some_variable = str()`

> By best practice I do not mean "which is best coding style/most readable" but rather factors such as memory consumption, speed and which on the whole is more reliable for general use.

Comment: All three of those will do the same thing. On a broader note, you may be interested in the [typing system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) if you are concerned about keeping track of variable types closely.

Comment: It is unusual to use the `str` constructor explicitly unless you're casting another type to a string.

Comment: The most natural "no value" value is `None`.

Comment: For the example shown, what you want is technically not an *empty* variable, but a variable initialized to the *identity* element for the operation you are going to use (which, in the case of string concatenation, is the empty string; but for multiplication, you would want to initialize the value to 1, for example).

Comment: This particular example would be much more natural as `s = ''.join(map(str, range(10)))`… Which makes the question moot…

Comment: You’d definitely use an empty string literal instead of `str()`. (Or, in this case, `''.join(map(str, range(10)))`

Comment: @deceze  Yes but this is just an example.  I meant in general.

Comment: What is your actual use case? Is this about initialisation to define the scope?

Comment: Yes, but the particulars of the context are important for what you would actually do. I think the one thing we can clearly say is that you probably would *not ever* use `str()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to initialize a variable to an empty value, using an empty value literal will be slightly faster, since it avoids having to do a name lookup.

That is, if you write:

```
some_variable = str()
```

Python first needs to make sure you haven't written something silly like

```
str = int
```

in some visible scope first, so it has to do a recursive name lookup.

But if you write:

```
some_variable = ''
```

Then there's no way that `''` will ever be anything but a `str`. (Similar principles apply for list and tuple literals: prefer `[]` and `()` over `list()` and `tuple()`.)

More generally, though: initializing a variable to an empty value is generally considered a code smell in Python. For things like an empty list, consider using a generator expression `(... for ... in ...)` or a generator function (using `yield`) instead -- in most cases you can avoid setting up empty values at all, and that's generally considered a more Pythonic style.

Comment: There are plenty of cases where a variable should (and must) be explicitly initialized; not every thing can or should be reduced to a generator or comprehension. Initializing a variable with a value that is never *used*, of course, is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @chepner: There are cases, but not as many as in some other languages. For example, it's totally fine (and encouraged!) to initialize a variable independently in separate branches of an `if` statement. I find that code written in a good Pythonic style frequently reduces or eliminates the need to initialize a variable with an invalid value just to overwrite it with a valid one later. Perhaps that's what you meant by "initializing with a value that is never used"? In that case I think we are very much in agreement.

Comment: Yeah, setting `x = 0; if some_condition(): x = 3 else x = 5` is an example where the initial definition of `x = 0` is unnecessary. I was also referring to `for` loops that build up lists using complex logic that either cannot be expressed with a list comprehension or are far more readable as regular loops.

Comment: @chepner: Sure, and those have their place, but I'd still advocate for using a generator function whenever possible rather than building up a list of results. (Although I just wrote some code that builds up a list eagerly rather than lazily this very morning, so I can agree that it is sometimes necessary -- but it feels less Pythonic to me than a generator would have been.)

Comment: Yes, but that's not really relevant to this question, only the particular example used to demonstrate the question.

Answer (score 6):

> I know Python is a dynamic language and declaring variables before-hand is generally not necessary

What? First of all how is declaring a variable before hand related to being dynamic or not? Secondly how can you even imagine any language that forbits declaring a variable "before-hand" (whatever that means) to work? You need to declare some variable directly at some point.

> Is there a difference between both of these and which is considered best practice?

Yes, there are differences. Consider this:

```
def str():
   return 1

x = str()
```

Python **does not** protect you from [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). But the literal empty string `''` cannot be shadowed. That's a difference on the functional level.

There is also a difference on the performance level: `x = ''` is slightly faster then `x = str()` due to being translated to a different bytecode. After all `x = ''` does not require a function call (which cannot be optimized again due to variable shadowing).

And finally esthethics: `x = ''` is probably more readable then `x = str()`. Again since you need to be sure what `str()` actually is in the context.

So all in all: go with `x = ''`.

Comment: Technically, declaration and definition are two separate things. (C, for instance, allows a variable to be declared without being defined.) Python doesn't have declarations separate from definitions; a variable is created only and immediately when a value is assigned to a name.

Comment: There's a difference between *forbidding* variable declarations beforehand and *not requiring* them. For the latter… *cough* PHP *cough* (to some degree)